# Retrieving values of Form::select

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have a select box with an array of data to populate it like this:

```
{!! Form::select('language',$languageArray,'null', ['id'=>'language','multiple',]) !!}
```

I am passing $languageArray with view , and is simply an array of values like ['A','B','C']...

Now while fetching the selected values i am getting numeric value of selected options. Is there a way to change the values from numeric indexes to Text written in option. i did it using an associative array as second argument like this:

```
['english' => 'English',
 'french' => 'French',
 'so on ...' => 'So On ..']
```

But it creates a long list and view seems to be overloaded with data is there a better way for achieving below output ???

```
<select name="language">
<option value="english" ">English</option>
<option value="french">French</option>
....
```

Comment: Where does `$languageArray` come from? Please show your controller code

Comment: Can you show us output of `$languageArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Config values ,

Create a file like languages.php in config folder.

```
<?php 
   return ['english' => 'English',
           'french' => 'French',
           'so on ...' => 'So On ..'
           'german'   => Lang::get('languages.german')
          ];
```

View :

```
{!! Form::select('language',Config::get('languages'),'null', ['id'=>'language','multiple',]) !!}
```

As you can see, in this way you can use config values in another view too and support multi language(its important too.. look at 'german')

Last Option is creating your own Form macro for example,

```
Form::macro('slugiySelect', function($name , $list , $selected = null , $options = [])
{
    $options = [];
    foreach($list as $row)
        $options[Str::slug($row)]  = $row;

    return Form::select($name , $options , $selected , $options);
});
```

In this macro your options array is slugify with Laravel string function and uses as a key , I kept value as yours. You can do it with your way.

Comment: Can you elaborate macro's a bit more. Thanks

Comment: @AliMalik HTML and Form macro's just a HTML code generator. Please check official Documentation from http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html . In addition that , i'm using Bootstrap Form Template so , i can easily change everyting from macros. Please check this  https://gist.github.com/mtigdemir/aa02f065c075cecb0d7a  example